# how to use find all method from BS4 to scrape certain strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<li class="sre" data-tn-component="asdf-search-result" id="85e08291696a3726" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/puppies">
  <div class="sre-entry">
    <div class="sre-side-bar">
    </div>
    <div class="sre-content">
      <div class="clickable_asdf_card" onclick="window.open('/r/85e08291696a3726?sp=0', '_blank')" style="cursor: pointer;" target="_blank">
```

I need to grab the string '/r/85e08291696a3726?sp=0' which occurs throughout a page. I'm not sure how to use the soup.find_all method to do this. The strings that I need always occur next to '

This is what I was thinking (below) but obviously I am getting the parameters wrong. How would I format the find_all method to return the '/r/85e08291696a3726?sp=0' strings throughout the page?

```
for divsec in soup.find_all('div', class_='clickable_asdf_card'):
    print('got links')
    x=x+1
```

I read the documentation for bs4 and I was thinking about using find_all('clickable_asdf_card') to find all occurrences of the string I need but then what? Is there a way to adjust the parameters to return the string I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BeautifulSoup`'s [built-in regular expression search](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) to find and extract the desired substring from an `onclick` attribute value:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"window\.open\('(.*?)', '_blank'\)")
for item in soup.find_all(onclick=pattern):
    print(pattern.search(item["onclick"]).group(1))
```

If there is just a single element you want to find, use `find()` instead of `find_all()`.

Comment: thanks, this worked out! I did not know about the reg ex search in BS4, very useful!